# Can't figure out mower deck parts after it broke?

Tags: lawnmower, craftsman

One of the sides of my mower deck has it's adjustment function broke and will not move up or down.

Here is the picture -

[image]

Seems simple.   But I don't really know how it was put together and when I visit (8 total parts websites), it seems to show the picture of the missing piece but the part isn't listed or sold.   So I have no idea what the part number is or what it is called.   But alas I may be looking at the diagram wrong or thinking about this incorrectly.

But if you use - https://www.jackssmallengines.com/jacks-parts-lookup/manufacturer/mtd/craftsman-sears/13-lawn-tractors/2015-models/13al78xt099-247-203744-t1600-2015/mower-deck - it seems I am mainly missing the big "j" hook that links this together.  This is right next to "33".   This part doesn't seem to be listed anywhere and I have no idea what it is called.

What do I need to order to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the possibly missing part is mirrored on the deck. In the linked diagram, it shows 65 and 66, spring and hook as the match for the section near the 33 part you've referenced.

Your photo shows an irregularity in that there is a cotter pin "tail" extending through the hole. Such a position is not something one would install in this manner, but would be the result of a failure of another component.

You should be able to match the side shown in the photo with the opposite side to confirm the missing parts are 65 and 66.

[image: deck parts image]

Comment: OK thank you - so I do not need 10 and 33?   I still can't figure out how this would have came out without me know.   My yard is bumpy though.

Comment: The photo isn't clear, but that cotter pin may be attached to the 66 part with the hook portion hidden behind the flange. It's unlikely that the J-hook has sheared off, considering how strong such parts can be. You'll need 10 and 33 on one side, 65 and 66 on the other.